# Need to fetch UnitPrice of a product

Tags: apex

I need to fetch UnitPrice value of PricebookEntry which has particuler ProductId. writting code below.

```
List<pricebookentry> sUnitPrice=[SELECT UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE product2Id=:productid];
  if(sUnitPrice.size()>0) {
  for(pricebookentry singlePricebookentry:sUnitPrice)
    iUnitPrice=sUnitPrice.UnitPrice;
  }
```

But this code is giving Exception:-

> > Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List < PricebookEntry>

Pls Help.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to do (without looking into the complete code)..

but focusing just on the error, you should change this line in the for loop

```
iUnitPrice = sUnitPrice.UnitPrice;
```

to

```
iUnitPrice = singlePricebookentry.UnitPrice;
```

Comment: A lot of  thanks, that's the catch.  and that was a silly mistake. :)